# Conciseness on a Title

Tags: grammar, titles

Consider the following sentence taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_AIR#AIR_13.0) Wikipedia page:

> It was numbered 13 to synchronize itself with the version numbering of Flash Player.

The statement implies the subsequent versions of the application are syncronized with the version of the Flash Player. In other words, the next version numbers have the same number as the Flash Player. I want to make a title based on the statement. I came up with the following:

> Synchronized Version numbers with of the Flash Player's

I somehow don't feel *correct* with the title!! What's wrong with the proposed title? Please shed some lights on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a changelog-styled title as is in your link:

> Version number synchronized with Flash Player

---

Here is your proposed title:

> Synchronized Version numbers with of the Flash Player's

This would be a sentence without the subject, which is perfectly valid for a changelog-styled title. However, there is only one version number which you synchronized, so it should read "number" instead of "numbers"; also, "with of the Flash Player's" is grammatically invalid and should be replaced with "with that of Flash Player" or "with Flash Player's", or more simply "with Flash Player".

Changed version 1:

> Synchronized version number with that of Flash Player

Changed version 2:

> Synchronized version number with Flash Player's

Changed version 3:

> Synchronized version number with Flash Player

I changed "Version" to "version" because there is no reason to use uppercase here.

Comment: Ooh, seems a very nice candidate title, I appreciate it :) But could you please elaborate on the status of my proposed title (grammatically, ...)

Comment: @goodUser done.

Comment: Wow, thank you, this is great. The only subtle issue is that the title is going to encompass all the following versions that are synchronized (the version 14, 15, 16, ... all are synchronized with the version of Flash player) thus, the plural form of the "number" is appropriate :)

Comment: @goodUser next time you should include the context as to where the sentence is used. Actually, you should include it now.

Comment: I don't get it!! I've already mentioned the page where the sentence is being used in my post!